# What operand to use for char type array?

Tags: c

I've got a silly problem and I just can get the hang of it.
  Have an easy C code (just want to find if string str1 starts with str2):

```
int main()
{
    int i, j; 
    char sir1[150], sir2[150], sir3[150];
    printf("insert the first string (sir1) and then hit ENTER \n");
    gets(sir1);
    printf("insert the second string (sir1) and then hit ENTER \n");
    gets(sir2);
    printf("\n");
    int len_sir2=strlen(sir2);
    for (i=0;i<len_sir2;i++)
    {
        sir3[i]=sir1[i];
    }

    for (j=0;j<len_sir2;j++)
    {
        if (sir3[i]!=sir2[i]){printf("String 1 does not start with String 2\n");break;return 0;}
    }
    printf("Sir1 starts with Sir2 \n");
    getch();    
}
```

My problem is that for the example "bananna" and "ana", the code just seems to have equal values for sir2[0] and sir3[0], even though in Quick Watch the values showed are 98'b' and 97'a'. What is that I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: The `return 0` after `break` has no effect.

Comment: what happens if `sir1` is smaller than `sir2`?

Comment: @moffeltje:that was just a sample...the second string (sir2) must be smaller or at least equal with the first one (sir1)

Comment: `if (strncmp(sir1, sir2, strlen(sir2)) == 0) { ... sir1 starts with sir2 ... }`

Answer (score 9):

One error is that you loop over `j`, but you use `i` inside the loop.

```
for (j=0;j<len_sir2;j++)
    {
        if (sir3[i]!=sir2[i]){printf("String 1 does not start with String 2\n");break;return 0;}
    }
```

Comment: Indeed...it's too early in the morning. Sorry for this, but I just keep banging my head and did not see I was using wrong letter...Thanks @Anonymous:)

Answer (score 1):

The statement `return 0;`is never reached. You break out of the loop before.

```
if (sir3[i]!=sir2[i])
{
  printf("String 1 does not start with String 2\n"); 
  break;  // <- not needed
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've removed the "break" statement but my problem and the reason I've opened the thread is that the comparison between sir3[i] and sir2[i] seems to do nothing; it is true even for different values. But thanks for your hint, it solved my other issue:)

Answer (score 0):

You should realise that `startsWith()` can be implemented as simply as:

```
int startsWith (char *a, char *b) {  // a.startsWith(b)
    return (strncmp (a, b, strlen (b)) == 0);
}
```

That's a bit "cleaner" than iterating over each character manually (just make sure you don't use `gets` in any "real" code, it opens you up to buffer overflow problems):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int startsWith (char *a, char *b) {  // a.startsWith(b)
    return (strncmp (a, b, strlen (b)) == 0);
}

int main (void) {
    char sir1[150], sir2[150];

    printf ("insert the first string (sir1) and then hit ENTER \n");
    gets (sir1);
    printf ("insert the second string (sir1) and then hit ENTER \n");
    gets (sir2);
    putchar ('\n');

    if (startsWith (sir1, sir2))
        printf ("sir1 starts with sir2 \n");
    else
        printf ("Sir1 does not start with sir2 \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hah, I just posted a comment to the same effect. I don't think you need the `strlen(a)` test... it's redundant and unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @Anonymous, good point, I was thinking that it would compare equal if either string reached the end but that's not so. Changed code to adjust and it's even shorter.